# How to merge csv files onto a single file on condition and adding file name as a column?

Tags: python, pandas, shell

I have multiple csv files on folder. The column headers are different but column datas are same.

The number inside the bracket is actual column name. Item(67) 67 is column name

So ignore the string Item and only consider the int inside () and perform the operation.

Sample Files: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1q7c1AqCRKRufSVh--9o0W6rdz28QyBGa

Explanation:

The files on the drive should be appended together. On Condition based on the column names. If the integer on condition matches with the column name(integer inside () of the column name) then it should be placed on that column. Please check the expected output.
    Files

```
File1: ID Item(67) Item (89) Item (91) Item (100)
       1    56      78        98        101     
       2    91      100       121       
File2: ID Item(96) Item (58) Item (99) Item (105)
       3  101      102        103       104
       4  112      113        117       119
```

Condition

```
d ={
    'File':['File1','File2'],
     'Price1':[67,67],
     'Price2':[89,67],
     'Price3':[91,67],
    'Price4':[100,91]
}
Condition=pd.DataFrame(data=d)
Condition
```

Expected Output:

```
  File  ID   Price1 Price2 Price3 Price4
  File1  1    56      78    98     101     
  File1  2    91      100   121
  File2  3    101     102  104     103       
  File2  4     112      113  119      117
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? have you written any code of some kind? Do post them.

Comment: I have for adding column names my code $ awk '{print FILENAME (NF?",":"") $0}' > 'FNR > 1' sheet*.csv > bigfile.csv It works but it adds header. But I don't how to do for condition part

Comment: It's really not clear to me what the file contents actually look like. I get that the column names are just numbers. damagedCoda is right, you should show or at least discuss what you've tried so far.

Comment: Do try this on your own, it'll be a learning experience. Refer [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/293775/merging-contents-of-multiple-csv-files-into-single-csv-file) link for help.
You'll need to dabble around a little with conditional statements and so on so forth.

Comment: @SimonHibbs actual file will look like Files check question I am new to shell i had written  code awk '{print FILENAME (NF?",":"") $0}' > 'FNR > 1' sheet*.csv > bigfile.csv  for merging but i want help after that

Comment: @damagedCoda sure will try could you please help on the problem?

Comment: Refer the post, once you have got some code up and running, post it and let's get to where you want okay?

Comment: Could you please help on the problem??

Comment: None of the sample files or output you've given are CSV format?

Comment: Will add @shawn

Comment: @Shawn please check

Comment: I see data, but no explanation of what is being done with it. Show code, clear specification, and most importantly...clear specifications. What do you want done with what you have, within what limits? By what rules? *Explain.*

Comment: @PaulHodges please check the edited question now.

Comment: Ok - in this example File1 is just reproduced as-is, but File2 gets the last 2 columns swapped. You are using "Condition" to control column order. Is there anything else?

Comment: This feel suspiciously like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189278/discussion-between-panda-and-paul-hodges).

Comment: @jezrael could you help this one

Comment: @panda - ya, it is simplier like before, but need some time.

Comment: @jezrael sure thanks for seeing it.  Can you help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
files = glob.glob('shelldemo/*.csv')

dfs = []
for fp in files:
    #if multiple columns with no ()  
    #df = pd.read_csv(fp, index_col=['S.no','id','number'])

    df = pd.read_csv(fp, index_col=['ID'])
    df['file'] = os.path.basename(fp).split('.')[0]
    df = df.set_index('file', append=True)
    df.columns = df.columns.str.extract('\((\d+)\)', expand=False).astype(int)
    dfs.append(df)


df1 = pd.concat(dfs, sort=False).reset_index()
print (df1)
   ID   file     58   67     89     91     96    100
0   1  file1    NaN   56   78.0   98.0    NaN  101.0
1   2  file1    NaN   91  100.0  121.0    NaN    NaN
2   3  file2  102.0  103    NaN    NaN  101.0  104.0
3   4  file2  113.0  117    NaN    NaN  112.0  119.0
```

---

```
print (df2)
    File  Price1  Price2  Price3  Price4
0  File1      67      89      91     100
1  File2      96      58     105      99
```

---

```
df2.columns = df2.columns.str.lower() 
df2['file'] = df2['file'].str.lower()

#merge data together by left join 
df = df1.merge(df2, on='file', how='left')
print (df)
   ID   file     58   67     89     91     96    100  price1  price2  price3  \
0   1  file1    NaN   56   78.0   98.0    NaN  101.0      67      89      91   
1   2  file1    NaN   91  100.0  121.0    NaN    NaN      67      89      91   
2   3  file2  102.0  103    NaN    NaN  101.0  104.0      96      58     105   
3   4  file2  113.0  117    NaN    NaN  112.0  119.0      96      58     105   

   price4  
0     100  
1     100  
2      99  
3      99
```

---

```
#filter integers between ()
df1 = df.loc[:, df.columns.str.isnumeric().isnull()].copy()
#filter all columns with price
df2 = df.filter(regex='price').copy()

uniq_vals_df2 = df2.stack().dropna().drop_duplicates()
not_matched_vals = np.setdiff1d(uniq_vals_df2, df1.columns)
df1 = df1.join(pd.DataFrame(columns=not_matched_vals.tolist() + ['a']))

#replace columns by match values from df2
for c in df2.columns:
    df2[c] = df1.lookup(df1.index, df2[c].fillna('a'))
#join to original DataFrame    
df = df[['file','ID']].join(df2)
```

---

```
print (df)

    file  ID  price1  price2  price3  price4
0  file1   1    56.0    78.0    98.0   101.0
1  file1   2    91.0   100.0   121.0     NaN
2  file2   3   101.0   102.0     NaN     NaN
3  file2   4   112.0   113.0     NaN     NaN
```

Comment: i may get numbers in condition that is not present in files in that case now it gives keyerror. Can you fill it np.nan?

Comment: @panda - Changed solution with 3 rows instaed `df1['a'] = np.nan` with `uniq_vals_df2 = df2.stack().dropna().drop_duplicates()
not_matched_vals = np.setdiff1d(uniq_vals_df2, df1.columns)
df1 = df1.join(pd.DataFrame(columns=not_matched_vals.tolist() + ['a']))`

Comment: i get InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects after running #replace columns by match values from df2
for c in df2.columns:
    df2[c] = df1.lookup(df1.index, df2[c].fillna('a'))

Comment: @panda - Need `df1 = df1.reset_index()` after `df1 = (pd.concat(dfs, keys=sheetnames, sort=False)
         .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
         .rename_axis('file')
         .reset_index())`

Comment: i get this error after running for c in df2.columns:
    df2[c] = df1.lookup(df1.index, df2[c].fillna('a'))
#join to original DataFrame    
df = df[['file','ID']].join(df2)
print (df)  ValueError: Row labels must have same size as column labels after including your code

Comment: hmmm, maybe also duplicates in `df2.index` ? If use `df2 = df2.reset_index()` not help it?

Comment: after df2.index also it doesn't help what should I do

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189381/discussion-between-panda-and-jezrael).

Comment: please check chat