# In python,how to get the rows from a data frame where a particular string is present in any of the column (String value)

Tags: python, string, pandas

My data frame contains `name`, `age`, `Task1`, `Task2`, `Task3`.
Now I need to get all the rows that satisfy a string value in either of `Task1`, `Task2`, `Task3` columns. Say I want to check 'Drafting', key word. If 'Drafting'  is present as part of any of these column value, then, that entire row has to be added to resultant frame.

I tried `isin()` but I am getting true or false. I need to extract such 'N' rows, that contain a particular keyword.
I tried,
`df.columns[df.Task1.str.contains("Drafting")]` , but this compare and give single column .
Any one know how to use, str.contains or any other method to compare string values of columns and get all rows that satisfy the checking condition.

```
  Name  Age              Task1    Task2            Task3
0  Ann   43  Drafting a Letter  sending           paking
1  Juh   29            sending   paking  Letter Drafting
2  Jeo   42            Pasting  sending           paking
3  Sam   59            sending  pasting  Letter Drafting
```

I need to check if the key word 'Drafting' is present in any of the columns[The column contains 3 to 4 words, need to check Drafting is present in this words/sentence]; the result should be:

```
  Name  Age              Task1    Task2            Task3
0  Ann   43  Drafting a Letter  sending           paking
1  Juh   29            sending   paking  Letter Drafting
3  Sam   59            sending  pasting  Letter Drafting
```

Comment: its advisable to create a sample (small) dataframe which demonstrates the issue and post as text. Also please do post an expected output showing the difference inpyt v/s output. This will help users to get a clear picture of what is needed and will drive more answers. Thanks

Comment: Hi, lay out please a small example of the original data

Comment: The string contains logic you want to implement is for **complete** word matches? Should `'raft'` match with `'Drafting'` or only the isolated word `'raft'` (which may appear in a sentence: `'I like to use a raft'`?

Comment: yes I need to get the columns that contain exactly 'Drafting' . No other combination(Regular expression is not useful).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or just(Note this will check entire df not specific columns):

```
df[df.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('Drafting')).any(axis=1)]
#for case insensitive use below
#df[df.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('Drafting',case=False)).any(axis=1)]

  Name  Age              Task1    Task2            Task3
0  Ann   43  Drafting a Letter  sending           paking
1  Juh   29            sending   paking  Letter Drafting
3  Sam   59            sending  pasting  Letter Drafting
```

Comment: I like this, though may need to match on something like `'(?<![a-zA-Z\-])Drafting'` if a word like redrafting is not meant to match.

Comment: @anky many thanks, as this is working for more than one word. Many thanks for your kind reply.

Comment: @Shara My pleasure. :)

Comment: @anky_91 could you please help me with the problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54944193/how-to-merge-csv-files-onto-a-single-file-on-condition-and-adding-file-name-as-a

Comment: @anky_91 How to search more than two words at a time?

Comment: @dondapati `str.contains('|'.join(list_of_words))` ?? if not , please can you post a fresh question. :) Thanks

Answer (score 3):

A quick comparison of given answers on 20k rows of data-

@Alollz (in comments)

```
%timeit df.loc[df.filter(like='Task').applymap(lambda x: 'Drafting' in x).any(1)]
25.2 ms ± 2.09 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

@Sergey Bushmanov

```
%timeit df[df.Task1.str.contains("Drafting") | df.Task2.str.contains("Drafting") | df.Task3.str.contains("Drafting")]
58.7 ms ± 9.25 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

@anky_91

```
%timeit df[df.filter(like='Task').apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('Drafting')).any(axis=1)]
88.6 ms ± 12.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit df[df.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('Drafting')).any(axis=1)]
128 ms ± 14.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

@ALollz

```
%timeit  df.loc[df.filter(like='Task').stack().str.split(expand=True).eq('Drafting').any(1).any(level=0)]
290 ms ± 29.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: how about `df.filter(like='Task').apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('Drafting')).any(axis=1)` ??

Comment: Bit less than previous but not close to @Sergey.

Comment: thanks for that. :) think calling the series individually wins on time but calling  them individually is manual.

Comment: I think the fastest is `df.loc[df.filter(like='Task').applymap(lambda x: 'Drafting' in x).any(1)]`. Though at the expense of the `Series.str.contains` NaN and error handling.

Answer (score 1):

You may try:

```
new_df = df[df.Task1.str.contains("Drafting") | df.Task2.str.contains("Drafting") | df.Task3.str.contains("Drafting")]
```

This will return a `new_df` with rows containing "Drafting" in any of the "Task1,2,3" columns.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using `np.where`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name': ['Ann', 'Juh', 'Jeo', 'Sam'],
    'Age': [43,29,42,59],
    'Task1': ['Drafting a letter', 'Sending', 'Pasting', 'Sending'],
    'Task2': ['Sending', 'Paking', 'Sending', 'Pasting'],
    'Task3': ['Packing', 'Letter Drafting', 'Paking', 'Letter Drafting']
    })

df_new = df.iloc[df.index[np.concatenate(
                np.where(df['Task1'].str.contains('Drafting')) +
                np.where(df['Task2'].str.contains('Drafting')) +
                np.where(df['Task3'].str.contains('Drafting'))).astype(int)
            ].values.tolist()]

print(df_new)

  Name  Age              Task1    Task2            Task3
0  Ann   43  Drafting a letter  Sending          Packing
1  Juh   29            Sending   Paking  Letter Drafting
3  Sam   59            Sending  Pasting  Letter Drafting
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try something like this,

```
new_df = df[(df['Task1'] == 'Drafting') | (df['Task2'] == 'Drafting') | (df['Task3'] == 'Drafting')]
```

This will select all the rows if the columns `Task1` or `Task2` or `Task3` contains 'Drafting`.

Comment: **equals**, not *contains*

Comment: I have to check a key word in the sentence of a column. Not the exact keyword. I have added a sample result requirement.